# Unix - Count line inside two files and sum the value

Tags: bash, function, shell, unix, operator-keyword

I want to count how much line within 2 files. I create function to get the value for each file, and sum it.
Here is the code :

```
count_sus_pop()
{
wc -l < ${SCRIPTDIR}/output/${OUTPUTFILE1}_${DATE}.csv
}

count_waive_pop()
{
wc -l < ${SCRIPTDIR}/output/${OUTPUTFILE2}_${DATE}.csv
}

if [$(count_sus_pop)+$(count_waive_pop) -gt 2];
then
pop="[POPULATION]"
else
pop=""
fi
```

If the summation result greater than 2, assign "[POPULATION]" to variable pop, else pop is empty.
My code doesn't work. Please give me your suggestion

Comment: What happens? What have you tried to do to solve it?

Comment: Why are you defining aliases in the functions?

Comment: @Barmar : edited! alias should not be there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to just use:

```
total_lines=$(cat "${SCRIPTDIR}/output/${OUTPUTFILE1}_${DATE}.csv" "${SCRIPTDIR}/output/${OUTPUTFILE2}_${DATE}.csv" | wc -l)
if [[ $total_lines -gt 2 ]]; then
    pop="[POPULATION]"
else
    pop=""
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some basic syntax errors in your script - I would suggest using [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) to fix those.

In terms of counting the combined number of lines, I would suggest this approach:

```
total_lines=$(cat "${SCRIPTDIR}/output/${OUTPUTFILE1}_${DATE}.csv" "${SCRIPTDIR}/output/${OUTPUTFILE2}_${DATE}.csv" | wc -l)
```

That is, use `cat` to combine the two files and use `wc -l` to obtain the total number of lines.

Your test would then be `if [ "$total_lines" -gt 2 ]` - note that the spaces are important.

Answer (score 1):

you need spaces around `[` and `]`. And the `test` operator doesn't perform arithmetic, so you need to use the shell arithmetic operator `$(( ))`

```
if [ $(( $(count_sus_pop)+$(count_waive_pop) )) -gt 2 ]
```

or you can use `bash`'s built-in `[[ ]]`` operator:

```
if [[ $(count_sus_pop)+$(count_waive_pop) -gt 2 ]];
```